# Why no code is executed after mainloop tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, mainloop

I know what is the purpose of mainloop (or at least i think), also i know that code placed after mainloop can be executed using after(), but why is like that? Why is mainloop blocking it?

Comment: What do you mean? The code running the main loop blocks because it is busy with running the main loop.

Comment: you could have at least explained what you **think** `.mainloop()` does, then we could tell what you got wrong and what right, also the closes comparison to `.mainloop()` is asynchronous code, basically there is a loop that runs till stopped that handles all the events, obviously nothing can run after the loop until the loop has finished

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.mainloop()` method, you start a special loop used by Tkinter to check for events like keypresses and button presses. It functions like a forever `while` loop. Therefore, you can't run any code outside of the loop until either the window is closed by the user or is destroyed in the code.

Comment: Yeah, that comparison to while loop really helped me. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! It would be nice if you could accept the answer so others will know this question has been answered